# ajax function still refreshes page when it shouldnt

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

#index.js

```js
const detail = document.getElementById('btc-price')
    
function loadPrices() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('GET', 'data.json', true)
    
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
      detail.textContent = data.cryptos.BTC
    }
  }

  xhr.send()
}
    
setInterval(loadPrices(), 2000)
```

#index.html

```html
<body>
  <p>BTC: <span id="btc-price"></span></p>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

#main.py

```py
import cryptocompare
from time import sleep
import json
    
count = 0
while True:
  coins    = cryptocompare.get_price(['BTC', 'ETH', 'DOGE', 'ADA', 'XLM'], 'USD')
  name_lst = [x for x in coins.keys()]
 price_lst = [x.get('USD') for x in coins.values()]
    
 prices    = dict(zip(name_lst, price_lst))
 json_dict = {'cryptos': prices}
    
 with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
   data = json.dump(json_dict, f)
    
   with open('data.json') as f:
     info   = json.load(f)
     count += 1
     print('finished', count)
     sleep(3)
```

I have a function that loads the prices of cryptocurrencies from a data.json file that is being updated by constantly by main.py, it all works well but when the price gets updated the page gets refreshed which is not supposed to happen in this case, i have no idea why its behaving this way, any help is appreciated!

Comment: there is no form element involved? Just the code shown?

Comment: why is a form necessary?

Comment: It’s not - it would explain the page reload. I was just checking

Comment: Your code shouldn't be doing anything every 2 seconds. You're calling `loadPrices()` immediately when starting the timer, not passing the function to `setInterval`. You need to remove the `()` from the call.

Comment: Nothing in this code is reloading the page, it must be something else.